# How to see the console log in PhpStorm when running Angular

Tags: angular, logging, phpstorm, webstorm

I am running Angular in a PhpStorm IDE.

The code is fill with "console.log" calls, when console defined as `declare var console: Console;` Console in a interface in the lib.dom.d.ts library.

Anyway, I can't see this log anywhere! Where is the console window in PhpStorm?

Is there any simple way to define log in Angular? I saw something about ngx-logger library, but I didn't find any instructions of how to install this library.

Any help in angular log subject will be great!

Answer (score 0):

All logs from `console.log` you can see in browsers console (To open the developer console in Google Chrome, open the Chrome Menu in the upper-right-hand corner of the browser window and select More Tools > Developer Tools. You can also use the shortcut Option + ⌘ + J (on macOS), or Shift + CTRL + J (on Windows/Linux).) Also you don't need to declare console, it's global variable.

All logs in your code will be runed in browser (in runtime). In IDE you can see only build time logs.

Comment: that's not true, you can see `console.log` in IDE. see my answer above

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need starting your application in debugger to see the logging in [debugger console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.2/interactive-debugger-console.html).
Just try debugging your Angular application per instructions at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.3/angular.html#angular_running_and_debugging: start it with `npm start` command (either in terminal or using the corresponding run configuration), then use the [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.3/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration to attach the debugger to your page